# Updating your Joomla! files. Please wait ... (forever?)

Tags: update

I would like to update my site. This is what the update page says

```
Installed Joomla! version   3.2.0
Latest Joomla! version  3.2.3
Update package URL  http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/19240/158108/Joomla_3.2.x_to_3.2.3-Stable-Patch_Package.zip
```

Installation method is set to "Write files directly".

However, after starting the update process, it takes forever without ever ending.

**How to make the update work?**

*Note: I have read that it may have to do with some PHP settings, but I could not make it work. [Example 1](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=750361)  and [example 2](http://www.hotjoomlatemplates.com/blog/joomla-installation/164-problems-with-joomla-25-update)*

Some of my settings:

- Directory Permissions are all on "writable".
- Log and temp path do
  exist (I use a url rewrite for public access, but I have checked the paths are correct according to the recommendation on the hotjoomlatemplates page)

Update: This is an excerpt from joomla_update.php

```
2014-04-22T20:15:06+00:00   INFO    update  Update started by user Super User (279). Old version is 3.2.0.
2014-04-22T20:15:06+00:00   INFO    update  File Joomla_3.2.x_to_3.2.3-Stable-Patch_Package.zip successfully downloaded.
2014-04-22T20:15:06+00:00   INFO    update  Starting installation of new version.
```

In `error.php` is no significant information.

Comment: Can you check your PHP error log? It sounds like the script times out while trying to do the work.

Comment: @Bakual I have added an excerpt, are these the two files you mean?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that it has something to do with rights. The folder is writable, you say, is it writable for everyone (chmod 777)? PHP might be blocking some stuff. Also, I'm not sure about this, but does the executing file have the correct rights, might have no effect, but who knows?

Comment: I meant the server error log. If you don't have access to that one, you need to ask you hoster.
Also make sure you have error reporting set to maximum in your Joomla global configuration. It will make sure the errors are either shown or written to the log.

Comment: And just for reference for the love of god never use 777 permissions :P

Comment: @Bakual No I have not direct access to the PHP error log. I did not take this extra step in the end but did a semi-automatic update via the Hosters Installatron Tool, which executes steps similar to "manual update" I guess. This worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is always possible to download the Joomla update from http://www.joomla.org/download.html and use the standard Install process. The end result is the same as using the built-in updater.

Comment: Well, this doest not really answer the question, but this is what I finally did, thus accepting this answer. To be exact I used the Installatron Tool (http://installatron.com/) provided by my hoster, which executes steps similar to "manual update" I guess. This worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest turning on the built in developer tools in your browser and monitoring the network requests being made.  Each "step" in the update process is being done via AJAX and it's possible there's an error message not being displayed on the page but it can be found by reviewing the contents of each request.

Comment: This did not help I just saw the Progress Page downloaded with the forever spinning wheel. Remember, this is about an update of the site, not accessing actual content.

Comment: As I noted, you need to turn on your browserr's developer tools during the update to try and catch any "hidden" errors that leave your site sitting on the spinning wheel.  For example, if there is a PHP error, it will break the expected response format and the JavaScript that is listening for that response will never process because it didn't get a valid response.  Monitoring requests through the browser's tools will let you see these errors.

Answer (score 1):

I notice sometimes the error can have an issue right at the end. If it mysql updates, it can be fixed with an extra step, if it is files then most likely you will need to restore from backup.

If its during the download process then the answer Adriel Brunson gave is perfect, this would skip that step.

The additional step with mysql is navigate to the extension manager and go to the database tab. If you see an error there it can typically be fixed through the "fix" button.

If as Michael stated and there is an issue with the ajax calls being made, then unless the error is a plugin stopping the request there is not much you can do without getting really deep into that Joomla install.

The last thing is to ensure your server configuration is optimal for Joomla, if say zip/unzip is not available that could cause it to fail (as well as installing other extensions).

Sometimes we have issues with updates, this is my findings and ways I have gotten around it, though it may not work in all cases.

Comment: The database is reported OK, before and after the update trials.